# how to get a property of a jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In the code below  I'm attaching a jquery ui dialog to my div "#myDiv".

After it is initialised, how can get the value of one of its properties? I tried `$('#myDiv').dialog.model` but it wont work?

```
    $('#myDiv').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 400,
                height: 450
        }); 



alert($('#myDiv').dialog.model); // it must alert "true"
```

Comment: 'model' could be 'modal'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv').dialog('option', 'modal');
```

or

```
$('#myDiv').dialog('option').modal;
```

or

```
$('#myDiv').dialog('option')['modal'];
```